# How to convert string into 2D List based on given condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I am taking a string as input. I have to convert into a 2D list or matrix if `@` represents columns and `#` represents rows.

Example: `1@-2@3#-3@2@4#-7@8@9` into `[[1,-2,3],[-3,2,4],[-7,8,9]]`.

This is my code. I couldn't get exact result.

```
a = input()
b = a.split('#')
c = [list(word) for word in b]
print(c)
```

But this gives me

```
[['1', '@', '-', '2', '@', '3'],
 ['-', '3', '@', '2', '@', '4'],
 ['-', '7', '@', '8', '@', '9']]
```

(`'-'` belongs to next element its not a expression like `'-2'`)

Comment: Split on @ in the comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. `c = [list(word) for word in b]` converts each character in a word into a separate element. To prevent that, group the elements the way you like into a list first:

```
c = [word.split('@') for word in b]
```

If you want to make the entries integers, you have to do that explicitly:

```
c = [[int(item) for item in word.split('@')] for word in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `split` to perform the row-wise and column-wise splits on `#` and `@` respectively, and `map` cells to `int`:

```
s = "1@-2@3#-3@2@4#-7@8@9"

print([list(map(int, x.split("@"))) for x in s.split("#")])
```

Output:

```
[[1, -2, 3], [-3, 2, 4], [-7, 8, 9]]
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/BabyishAzureProfiles)